# Covert List data into Hierarchical data

Tags: java, list, hierarchy

I would like to Convert List data into Hierarchy. Looking for sample code.

```
Class State{
     String stateName;
     List<County> counties;
}
Class County{
     String countyName;
     List<Town> towns;
}
Class Town{
     String townName;
     List<House> houses;
}
Class House{
     String streetName;
     String houseNo;
}
```

**Data is in the file or DB resultset**

```
State, County, Town, House
NY   , Cook,   Main,  123
NY   , Cook,   Madison, 456
NY   , Hudson, River Rd, 123
NY   , Hudosn, River Rd, 456
NY   , Hudosn, River Rd, 789
```

I assume that State is unique since I've this in where claouse.
The result will be one instance of State.

So far I've tried this. I know its comepletely wrong, there has to be some sort of recursion to be used but I'm totally getting confused.

```
        for (Address addrs:resultList) {
        state.setStateName(addrs.getStateName());
        county = new County();
        county.setLoc(addrs.getCountyName);
        townList = new ArrayList<Town>();               

        town = new Town();
        town.setTownName(addrs.getTownName());
        houseList = new ArrayList<House>();

        House house = new House();
        house.sethouse(addrs.getStreetName());
        house.setStatus(addrs.getHouseNo());

        houseList.add(house);
        town.sethouses(houseList);

        townList.add(town);
        loc.setConEntities(townList);
        locations.add(loc);
    }

    state.toJason() .....
```

Comment: Loop through and compare with old value, if changed then create new one else add it to old one. Getting bit confused and getting lost.

Comment: Can you add the relevant code to the question?

Comment: added code which I've started with

Answer (score 0):

Try to think about it like this; every row has information from the top to the bottom of the hierarchy. Instead of creating a new instance of County, Town, etc. for every row you should just check if that object already exists and only update it if it does. So for example, in the first row the county is Cook. Since the hierarchy doesn't contain that county we create an instance of County and save it to the hierarchy. When we encouter Cook in the next row we can just retrieve that object from the hierarchy and update it with the Town and house. This approach is obviously also applicable to towns (in your example). Consider using a [Map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html)